# How to separate order review and payment methods sections in WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

**Problem:**

on the checkout page (`form-checkout.php`) the following action code calls the review order AND the payment method section at the same position (after each other)

```
do_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review');
```

However, I want the `order review` and `payment method` sections to be separate, i.e. to call them individually in different places on the checkout page.

**Solution attempt:**

I came across guidance here and found the file `includes/wc-template-hooks.php` where the above action is created with he following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 ); 
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
```

So to test and call ONLY the payment section separately, I went back to `form-checkout.php` and tried this:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_payment' );
```

or this

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_payment',99 );
```

But neither calls the payment section!

**Could anyone please help me understand why this doesn't work?**

Note: I know I can register hook the woocommerce_checkout_payment to a custom function and call it that way, but I'm confused as to why the direct method doesn't work and I'd prefer to keep things simple were possible.

Comment: What does it mean to **splite** them?

Comment: Thank you both, I have clarified it further. With splitting, I mean to show the 2 sections separately in different parts of the page, while woocommerce_checkout_order_review calls both together.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec No, I just want to call woocommerce_order_review and woocommerce_checkout_payment separately on the checkout page. At the moment woocommerce_checkout_order_review calls both at the same time, so I cannot show these sections in different places.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Why would that be? I tested creating a custom function to hook 'woocommerce_checkout_payment' and to call the custom function then in different places on the checkout pages and it works fine. Just the direct method of calling 'woocommerce_checkout_payment' doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: The new location is probably the main factor. I tested with the `woocommerce_before_order_notes` hook and it works fine. Maybe your theme has a different layout. Test other hooks. You can make sure your code is working properly by inserting templates and an `echo` for example `echo 'test';`

Comment: Thank you both! I'm probably just too inexperienced, but the main question is: why do you need to hook 'woocommerce_checkout_payment' onto something (add_action()). Why can you not just call this directly with do_action(woocommerce_checkout_payment)? I mean 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' is also called directly with do_action, why is this not possible for 'woocommerce_checkout_payment'?

Comment: You are making confusions: `do_action` is action hook itself (with a unique name) where all the attached functions will be executed in this specific location, `add_action` attach a function to a hook, `remove action` detach a hooked function from an hook…

Comment: Yep, I know and my question is why then does this not work: do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_payment' );

Comment: Sorry `do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_payment' );` can't work as `do_action()` requires a hook name, not a function name as `woocommerce_checkout_payment` which is a function name called in `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` hook. See [`woocommerce_checkout_payment()` function code source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.2/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2265-L2287)

Comment: Ah okay thank you. So there is now way to execute a function directly in the template, you always need to go the additional step of hooking the function onto something?

Comment: @AlphaX You can add your own hook in the template like `do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_payment_hook' );`… Then in your functions.php theme file add `remove_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );` and `do_action('woocommerce_checkout_payment_hook', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 10 );` so payment section will be detached from `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` hook and attached to your own hook location…

Comment: Yes, I have already done this, that's not a problem, thx. I'm just trying to understand conceptually why the function woocommerce_checkout_payment cannot be called directly in the template file (without first going the extra step via function.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines to `functions.php` in your child-theme:

```php
// Detaching `payment` from `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` hook
remove_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
// Attaching `payment` to my `woocommerce_checkout_payment_hook`
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_payment_hook', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 10 );
```

now you can use the custom hook to show the `payment` section:

```php
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_payment_hook' );
```

P.S. Thank you @LoicTheAztec for the solution.